# OutOfMemoryException running the 8.1->8.2 upgrade wizard

Tags: upgrade

On Step 3 of 1.2.3 in the upgrade guide, I'm getting a `System.OutOfMemoryException` pointing to `Sitecore.Update.Utils.FileUtils.SerializeFile(Stream stream, String location)` +137.

Installation wizard installed fine and the `UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx` page comes up fine.

In `/sitecore/admin/packages`, it looks like, it tried to write the file "Upgrade from 8.1 rev. 160519 to 8.2 rev. 160720.update", but it's got zero length.

Any ideas?

Comment: How much memory you have in this system ?

Comment: 16gb, 47% used.

Comment: Can  you post the full stacktrace, please?  Might help clue someone in, as to what might be going on.

Comment: have you changed the maxAllowedContentLength setting (1.2.3 step2) ? Also, do you have correct file/folder level permission setup for filesystem ?

Comment: Also if you can post anything you see related in the log where this exception was captured is helpful

Comment: [OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   Sitecore.Update.Utils.FileUtils.SerializeFile(Stream stream, String location) +137
   Sitecore.Update.Update.Engine.AggregatedPackage.ExtractUpatePackage(String aggregatedPackagePath, AggregatedUpdatePackageEntryInfo updatePackageInfo, String targetPath) +346

Comment: Sitecore.Update.UpdateInstallationWizard.InstallationWizard_ActiveStepChanging(Int32& newPageNumber, Boolean& changePage) +530
   Sitecore.Update.UpdateInstallationWizard.InstallationWizard_NextButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs args) +44
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692746
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562

Answer (score 4):

You must change the **maxAllowedContentLength** setting to increase the maximum allowed download size of the update package.
To do this:

In a text editor, in the \wwwroot\\Website\sitecore\admin\web.config file, change the **maxAllowedContentLength** setting from:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000" />
```

to:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4194304000" />
```

for more information check the upgrade document:
[Upgrade Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/80F3ABB82AB44D6AA5722F6B654CF2A8.ashx)

Comment: Ahh man, I kept changing this at the root web.config level.